# Is there any documentation on Powershell Programming in VS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, powershell

I'm looking for material on Powershell dev in visual studio.  Creating snap-ins with cmdlets.

I've seen the wrox book but it doesn't have great reviews.

Comment: Unfortunately the Wrox book is the only book which by default makes it the best book :). I own the Wrox book and it I found helpful in getting me started in writing cmdlets.

Comment: I have it from a reliable source that the wrox book sold less than 50 copies. That's what happens when you copy/paste MSDN content into a manuscript. Well done on getting one of the first fifty copies Chad! :D

Comment: Ah, a rare book indeed--I best put it in a protective case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good (little more than getting started) is [here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/04/10/chapter-20-your-own-cmdlets-and-extensions.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Micrsoft developer network has the following documentation about the Powershell SDK:
[MSDN Powershell Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)